# Symfony Twig Templating: Multiple embedding

Tags: symfony, twig

I have 3 files:

- kitchen.html.twig
- livingroom.html.twig
- chair.html.twig

And now I want to embed the **chair** into **kitchen** and **livingroom**. How can I do this? Neither embed, include nor extend seems the right way.

Sadly the twig documentation is just a list of code, but there is no usecase example for using this stuff. :\

I hope someone can help me whit this,
cheers,
SE64

EDIT: On top of that, chair.html.twig holds variables, which has to be "filled up" differently in **kitchen** and **livingroom**.

Comment: what you have tried? I suppose a simple `{% include 'chair.html.twig' %}` would work

Comment: Absolutley, yes. Thanks. I forgot one thing and eddited my post right now. Its a little bit more complex". Even if thats still far away from beeing complex. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `with` attribute of the `include` function.

Suppose chair.html.twig uses a variable named "material", then in **livingroom.html.twig** you include like this:

```
{% include 'chair.html.twig' with {'material': 'wood'} %}
```

and in **kitchen.html.twig** you include like this:

```
{% include 'chair.html.twig' with {'material': 'metal'} %}
```

Comment: Perfekt! :) Thanks.